# How to set a listener on Firebase value event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, raspberry-pi, firebase-realtime-database

How to properly set up a value event listener with Firebase, using Node.js?

I'm reading through [Firebase's documents](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write), **and have successfully been able to update tables and rows on my Firebase database** from both my Mac, and my Raspberry Pi running at the same time, connected to the same Firebase database; however, I'm not able to understand what I need to do with this segment for making a listener on a value event:

```
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

It's **evident** to me that I need somehow need to define `postElement` based on the output:

```
FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. ReferenceError: postElement is not defined
```

*However, I have not idea what `postElement` is supposed to be, nor how to define it. Help!*

I've made a very small program and table to simply update/change values. And I changed the program to I can see up console output when a row it changed.

This is my small user data variable, just so you now how little data I'm trying to change:

```
var user = {
    id:Number,
    name:String,
    number:Number
};

var users = [user];
```

And this is my change to the documentation code, so I can see something in the console output while Node.js is running:

```
var userRef = firebase.database().ref('/users/user' + users[0].id);
userRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
    firebase.app.updateUserInfo(postElement, snapshot.val());
    console.log('Users' + users[0].name + ' changed.');//<- this is the line I added.
});
```

NOTE: `updateStarCount` function is from the example in the Firebase documentation, meaningful to the example there, which I cautiously assume updates the local Firebase db...

NOTE2: If `updateStarCount` is doing some other magic, then it is a documentation flaw with Firebase, because the function isn't defined there. Any help clarifying this documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is this `updateStarCount` function coming from? It's definitely not from Firebase.

Comment: @vzsg if you check the link to the [Firebase page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write) and search for `updateStarCount` you'll find it in the linked page.

Comment: Ah, I see. I should have phrased it as "not from the Firebase SDK". This is just example code, not much more concrete than pseudocode. The idea there assumes that you have a function that updates an HTML element with the results — which you must replace with your own logic in a real application.

Comment: @vzsg Gotcha... I guess an expansion to my question is, how to understand this documentation example? Everything is pretty clear up until that point.

Comment: Imagine a web application where there are posts with ratings that are displayed as stars... Note that you are reading the Web guide (browser JavaScript), not the Node Admin SDK's guide.

Comment: @vzsg That was enormously helpful! The documentation has so many links everywhere, it can easily be misleading...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to make this question helpful for other people looking into same problem, here's an extended example from the question with missing functions and variables defined:

```
// some HTML element on the page
var postElement = document.getElementById("postElement");

// here I will assume that this function simply 
// updates the contents of the element with a value
var updateStarCount = function(element, value) {
    element.textContent = value;
};

var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    updateStarCount(postElement, snapshot.val());
});
```

With this JavaScript you can assume HTML page which looks like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="postElement"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Following IgorNikolaev's example... In order to make this post more useful to people having the same problem with Node.js on Raspberry Pi's or as a standalone app (not for a web page).

Thanks to @vzsg, the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/save-data) may be better suited to my situation.

Steps to create a fully working example are...

This only covers writing to a database, results of which can be seen when logged into Firebase's console.

First, [create Firebase admin authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start), then:

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp({
    credential:admin.credential.cert("/path/to/credential/cert.json"),
    databaseURL: "databaseURLhere"
});

var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("/");
console.log('DB ref: ' + ref);

var usersRef = ref.child("users");
```

Use `set` to create new values in the database. **But be careful**, `set` overwrites pre-existing values.

```
usersRef.set({ //With completion callback.
    alanisawesome: {
      date_of_birth: "June 23, 1912",
      full_name: "Alan Turing"
    },
    gracehop: {
      date_of_birth: "December 9, 1906",
      full_name: "Grace Hopper"
    }
  },
  function(error) { //NOTE: this completion has a bug, I need to fix.
    if (error) {
      console.log("Data could not be saved." + error);
    } else {
      console.log("Data saved successfully.");
    }
});
```

Append new columns (or change current data) to row with `update`, **but be extra careful** to give the paths to column, otherwise all previous columns are overwritten, instead of appending to the table:

```
usersRef.update({
    "alanisawesome/nickname": "Alan The Machine",
    "gracehop/nickname": "Amazing Grace"
  },
  function(error){
    if(error){
      console.log("Data could not be updated." + error);
    } else {
      console.log("Data updated successfully.");
    }
  });
```